# Php y msqli no estan insertando datos

Tags: php, html

Tengo un programa de login y registro. El problema es que al momento de registrar al usuario los datos no se estan guardando en mi base de datos

Este es el codigo en php del Registro

```html
<body background="Imagenes/pluma.jpg">
<form action="recibe_registro.php" method="post" >
<br>
 <center><table width="25%" border="0" id="form_pers">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> 
 <p> 
<label for="textfield1">Usuario:<br></label>
<input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario"  >
 </p>
 <p> 
<label for="textfield1">Contraseña:<br></label>
<input type="password" name="contrasena" id="contraseña"  >
 </p>
  
  <p> 
<label for="textfield1">Nombre(s):<br></label>
<input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre"  >
 </p>
  <p> 
<label for="textfield1">Apellido(s):<br></label>
<input type="text" name="ap" id="ap"  >
 </p>
 <p> 
<label for="textfield1">RFC:<br></label>
<input type="text" name="rfc" id="rfc"  >
 </p>
 <p> 
<label for="textfield1">Teléfono:<br></label>
<input type="text" name="tel" id="tel"  >
 </p>
  <p> 
<label for="textfield1">Dirección:<br></label>
<input type="text" name="dir" id="dir"  >
 </p>
 
 <p> 
<label for="textfield1">Ciudad:<br></label>
<input type="text" name="ciudad" id="ciudad"  >
 </p>
 <p> 
<label for="textfield1">País:<br></label>
<input type="text" name="pais" id="pais"  >
 </p>
  
  
  
</td>      
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table></center>

<center><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_pers" value="Enviar"></center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Y este es el php que inserta a la base de datos

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php 
include("conecta_pasarela.php");
 
 $id_prov="";
 $us=$_POST['usuario'];
 $contrasena=$_POST['contrasena'];
 $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
 $ap=$_POST['ap'];
 $rfc=$_POST['rfc'];
 $tel=$_POST['tel'];
 $dire=$_POST['dir'];
 $ciudad=$_POST['ciudad'];
 $pais=$_POST['pais'];     
 
 $sql=mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO registro values('".$id_prov."','".$us."','".$contrasena."','".$nombre."',,'".$ap."','".$rfc."','".$tel."','".$dire."','".$ciudad."','".$pais."')");       
  
        echo"<script type=\"text/javascript\">function redireccionar(){window.location=\"compras.php\";} window.onload = redireccionar;</script>";   
 
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tienes algun error?

Comment: el id de tu tabla es primary key ?

Comment: @alanfcm no me marca ningun error a la hora de registrar a un usuario. Simplemente no se insertan a la tabla.

Comment: @Alfredo asi es

Comment: Y si estas seguro que orden de los valores esté en el mismo orden que las columnas de la tabla? o sino usa `INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);` y por cierto entre tu variable **nombre** y **ap** existe doble coma.

Comment: @StephanieBBautista entonces no lo deberías estar incluyendo en tu query ya que tu gestor de bases de datos lo inserta por cuenta propia; es decir no colocar ni el nombre de la columna ni el valor de ese id

Comment: @SSVITT ya verifique y si estan en el mismo orden. De igual manera quite la coma y sigue sin insertar datos.

Comment: @Alfredo ya lo quite, sigue sin insertar datos :/

Comment: haz un var_dump($sql); y añade a tu pregunta dandole en editar el resultado de ejecutar con esta instrucción

Comment: prueba de este modo solo verificando que los nombres de las columnas que tiene tu tabla sea como las pongo yo y nos comentas; es decir coloque los nombres de las columnas primero y ya luego con values() las variables que te estan llegando pero como te digo solo verifica que el orden sea el mismo en tu tabla

Comment: $sql=mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO registro(us, contrasena, nombre, ap, rfc, tel, dire, ciudad, pais) 
values('$us','$contrasena','$nombre','$ap','$rfc','$tel','$dire','$ciudad','$pais')");     @StephanieBBautista

Answer (score 0):

Podrias verificar esto para comprobar que esta bien...

```
$insert = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO TABLA(Columna1, Columna2, etc)
VALUES('$VAR1','$VAR2',etc)") or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
```

Suerte

Answer (score 0):

Te comento algunos errores que noto en tu sentencia SQL:

1.- Incluyes una variable que tiene un valor de ID pero mencionas en los comentarios que es PK (Llave primaria) dado lo cual tu gestor lo incluirá de manera automática; por lo cual no es necesario lo incluyas

2.- Tienes entre `$nombre` y `$ap` doble coma, lo cual te generará error quita la que sobra

3.- Personalmente quitaría esa concatenación que hiciste en `VALUES()` para meter las variables a tu query

Dejando tu código de la siguiente manera

```
<?php

$sql=mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO registro(us, contrasena, nombre, 
ap, rfc, tel, dire, ciudad, pais)
VALUES('$us','$contrasena','$nombre','$ap','$rfc','$tel','$dire','$ciudad','$pais')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Varios factores pueden influir en que no puedas, insertar datos, Uno es que los datos no hayan sido capturados en los Textbox  y eso provoque que al momento de insertar si en tu tabla algún campo es **NO** nulo no se realiza la inserción, otro que en la consulta en la variable :

> ".$nombre."',,

Tienes una coma extra, otra situación que los datos de tu conexión tengan algún error, Es recomendable que revises bien tu código.

Suerte, Saludos